# Dynamically Collecting Data from 2 tables to add to another

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I have the following code to collect information for two sets of information, customers and products :

```
if(isset($_POST['q'])) {

$q = $_POST['q'];

$select = $db->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE Model LIKE '%$q%' OR Description LIKE '%$q%' ORDER BY id DESC");

} else {

$select = $db->query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id DESC");

}
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="q" /> <input type="submit" name="search" />
</form>
```

The code is duplicated across both products and customers. I would like to create another page that will let me type in a form field that auto-populates with each database table (customers/products) and, after information is selected, allow the update of a third table (invoices).

In the same page, I would like to allow the addition of as many "products" as the user would like, via an icon "+" sign next to each row of products.

What would be the best way to approach this?

Comment: Have you looked into [mySQL joins](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/)? They sort of combine your `SELECTs` into a virtual table.

Comment: I know about mySQL joins, but I want to make a permanent table that can be called on later on by the user.  For instance, the user will select a customer, and that customer will be saved by their id, then the user will select a number of different products, also saved by their id, afterwards - when the user accesses a certain page, the page will list their selected items joined with that particular customer.